# FOR SHARE and FOR UPDATE statements in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sequelize.js

Regular SQL queries can contain ‘SELECT FOR SHARE’ and ‘SELECT FOR UPDATE’ statements when we use transactions.

Is there a way to set up the same statements with Sequelize? I have not found those options. May be there are some tricks?

What it’s required for, you can read here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html#locking-read-examples

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I’ve found out a bit. In Sequelize.j when we use findAll and findOne we can pass a ‘lock’ option. For example:

```
User.findAll({
   lock: transaction.LOCK.UPDATE // or SHARE, KEY_SHARE, NO_KEY_UPDATE
})
```

But sequelize.js uses ‘LOCK_IN_SHARE_MODE’ statement instead of ‘FOR SHARE’ statement. Mostly they are the same.

`KEY_SHARE` and `NO_KEY_UPDATE` are used only for PostgreSQL.