# Sequelize is not skipping the locked row

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

Here is my table:

```
+--+--------+---------+
|id|fullName|balance  |
+--+--------+---------+
|1 |  User  |10.000000|
+--+--------+---------+
```

**Scenario:** One operation is going to update the `User`'s balance to 20.000000. The second operation should select the row if it is not locked (If the row is locked by other operation, the select query should return `null`).

I'm implementing the mentioned scenario like this:

```
(async () => {
    updateOne()
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    select()
})()


let updateOne = async () => {

    const t = await db.transaction();
    try {

        await User.update({balance: 20.000000}, { where: { id: 1 } }, { transaction: t, lock: true })

        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000)) //5s delay
        await t.commit()

    } catch (e) {
        throw e
    }
}

let select = async () => {

    const t = await db.transaction();
    try {

        let users = await User.findAll({transaction: t, lock: true, skipLocked: true} )

        console.log(users)

        await t.commit()

    } catch (e) {
        throw e
    }
}
```

I'm using `setTimeout()` to ensure that the `select()` will select the row when `update()` is updating it (to make them parallel).

**What do I expect to happen?**

The `console.log(users)` should log `null` because the `update()` hasn't committed (because of the 5s delay) and `select()` should skip the locked row.

**What is actually happening?**

The `console.log(users)` logs the user and doesn't skip the locked row.

> *Dialect: MySQL*
>
> *Sequelize version: 6.3.5*

How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, how did you solved this problem ? if so

Comment: Dear @ch3ll0v3k; I changed my approach, I used a pessimistic lock using a transaction to solve this. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55456898/13090132

Comment: thx.
i have migrated to MariaDB v10.7.3, there is native ROW-LOCK, that does the job for me